# Swift - Help creating structure for JSON data

Tags: swift, swift4

i'm new to JSON but i do understand some of the basics. Excuse my terminology but i created a JSON file with multiple objects within objects that have arrays if that makes sense lol, correct me if i'm wrong.

I'm trying to create a structure or whichever method is best so i can retrieve the data use JSON Decoder. What confuses me is when having those arrays of data within those nested objects.

It'll be best to show you my json data and if you could me build the right type of structure.

It will initially just pull the first objects into a TableView as the headers then the object below it will be their own TableView sections. Once the user chooses a section like "Building a business", it then pulls all the content from that section.

JSON:

```
{
    "Ian Prukner": {
        "Building a business": [
            {"contentTitle":"Part 1", "URL":"URL1"},
            {"contentTitle":"Part 2", "URL":"URL2"},
            {"contentTitle":"Part 3", "URL":"URL3"}
        ],
        "Partnership": [
            {"contentTitle":"Part 1", "URL":"URL1"},
            {"contentTitle":"Part 2", "URL":"URL2"},
            {"contentTitle":"Part 3", "URL":"URL3"}
        ],
        "Motivation": [
            {"contentTitle":"Part 1", "URL":"URL1"},
            {"contentTitle":"Part 2", "URL":"URL2"},
            {"contentTitle":"Part 3", "URL":"URL3"}
        ]
    },
    "Hector Lamarque": {
         "Overcoming Objections":[
            {"contentTitle":"Overcoming Objections", "URL":"URL1"}
          ],
          "Personal Development":[
            {"contentTitle":"Overcoming Objections", "URL":"URL1"}
          ]
    }
}
```

I might need to re-structure my JSON data itself with identifiers of some sort.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Are you getting some sort of error when trying to read this? At first glance this all looks valid. Arrays are perfectly legitimate value types. Also check out swiftyJSON - makes dealing with json a bit easier https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: Have a look at [quicktype.io](https://quicktype.io)

Comment: Your JSON is very difficult to parse since none of the keys is known at ahead of time. If you want something that can easily work with `Decodable`, consider reformatting your JSON to something like this: https://pastebin.com/VtN0R49d

Comment: @CodeDifferent Thanks alot man for that code, that really helps me understand JSON more. I used MwcsMac's quicktype.io link and allowed me to convert it into swift code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know it is also possible to do the reverse? Create a struct with your data and make it conform to the 'codable' protocol. Now you can use JSONEncoder:

```
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
if let json = json {
   print("JSON:\n" + String(describing: json) + "\n")
}
```